# How to get Peewee ORM contains column working with join

Tags: python, peewee

I'm doing a join across two tables, pretty simple set up, but when I add a `contains` or `startswith` that references a column in the table being joined I can never get the results. No errors, but the count is always 0, despite me knowing that the records exist and being able to write the equivalent query in raw SQL and have it return all the results I expect.

Here's what it looks like, assume A and B are tables, they're related through a foreign key, and both the fields I'm using in the where clause are `CharField`.

This version does not work despite me expecting it to:

```py
(A.select().join(B).where(
    A.some_column.contains(B.other_column)
))
```

But this does work as expected:

```py
(A.select().join(B).where(
    SQL("t1.some_column ILIKE '%%' || t2.other_column || '%%'")
))
```

I would expect those two to be equivalent, but they're not. Looking at the output SQL from the first one it looks like this:

```sql
(SELECT "t1"."some_column" from "A" as "t1"
INNER JOIN "B" as "t2" ON ("t1"."b_id" = "t2"."id")
WHERE ("t1"."some_column" ILIKE %s)', ['%<CharField: B.other_column>%'])
```

The interesting thing to me about the SQL output is at the end where it's referencing `B.other_column`. I'm guessing that if it were `t2.other_column` instead then the query would work, but how do I make peewee do that? I've tried everything I can think of and I can't figure out a pure ORM way to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains` method performs interpolation of the parameter.

To achieve what you're trying to do, you would stay away from the "contains" method and use the ILIKE operation.

```
A.select().join(B).where(
    A.some_column % ('%' + B.other + '%'))
```

The first "%" is the operator overload for ILIKE. The `'%' + B.other + '%'` will concatenate the wildcards for substring search.

---

UPDATE: I felt like this was a legit issue, so I've made a small change to make the `.contains()`, `.startswith()` and `.endswith()` methods work properly when the right-hand-side value is, for example, a field. Going forward it should work more intuitively.

Commit here: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/0c98f3e1f556eba10cbbdf7c386c49c64f4da41c

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! That commit is an example of why I love peewee - it usually behaves in a way that is intuitive to me.